# Cannot seem to get bash history along with others working

Tags: bash, users, bashrc, history

This is very similar to all the other questions out there but at the same time not.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-59-generic x86_64) to be precise.

I successfully setup a new user with: `useradd -m webuser`, however, no matter what I do I cannot seem to get most the bash functions like auto complete and history to work.

For example my bashrc file has:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

but when I `echo "$HISTFILESIZE"` I do not get `null` but I do not get a result either:

```
$ echo "$HISTFILESIZE"
```

(Unfortunately this site doesn't allow me to actually show you since it tries to be very intelligent).

This goes for all history variables.

No matter what I do I cannot seem to get the basic environment variables to work and, as it seems the `.bashrc` to be read.

Ontop of this my set -o is pathetically small:

```
Current option settings
errexit         off
noglob          off
ignoreeof       off
interactive     on
monitor         on
noexec          off
stdin           on
xtrace          off
verbose         off
vi              off
emacs           off
noclobber       off
allexport       off
notify          off
nounset         off
nolog           off
debug           off
```

and all the question I try don't help, i.e.: https://superuser.com/questions/174306/how-can-i-enable-the-bash-command-history

I am logging in using SSH via PuTTY.

#### Edit

Output of echo $0 straight from the ssh temrinal:

```
$ echo $0
-sh
```

Comment: Are you definite you are using bash? What is the output of `echo $0`?

Comment: @Sparhawk the output is `-sh`, I assume I am using bash because I am using the same terminal and login method as I do for root whose profile works fine

Comment: Are you sure that it's `-sh` and not `sh`?

Comment: @Sparhawk added it fully to the question

Comment: Sounds like if PuTTY would not start a proper login shell maybe it just starts a ssh Connection to the PC and then lauches bash as if you would just run the command bash inside of a already existing Shell on the Local Machine. It may help to do a source .bashrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what `-sh` is, but you might be using `sh`, not `bash`. From memory, new users default to `sh`. To make them automatically use bash, modify `/etc/passwd` with root permission. e.g. one of

```
sudo vim /etc/passwd
sudo nano /etc/passwd
gksu gedit /etc/passwd
```

Then, find the line with your username in it. Change the final part from (e.g.) `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`. Restart the terminal or log in/out again.

Comment: Yep that was it exactly thanks! Never knew that

Comment: No worries. I've struggled through exactly the same problems, and it certainly wasn't obvious to me at the time!